# Reconnect an IBOutlet that got disconnected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, interface-builder, iboutlet

When I am setting an ***IBOutlet*** property (e.g. to an UIImageView of my storyboard) to '**nil**', I presume my property gets disconnected from this UIImageView.

How can one - programmatically - reconnect it further down the line to make it again be a reference to the very same UIImageView of my storyboard?

Comment: Why would you do that?  Anyway, if you set a tag then you can use `viewWithTag` on your root view to find it.

Comment: @Paulw11: Did that already but you only get a tag of the *'View'* of your UIImageView! If you assign it back to the property it says: incompatible pointer UIView *_Nullable -> UIImageView* - same with superview or casting...

Comment: @Paulw11: I have to do this to get rid of any reference for memory-management's sake! So I have to reconnect programmatically with a system hook that doesn't retain my reference, otherwise the memory doesn't get purged ;-)

Comment: That still doesn't make sense. IBOutlet properties should be weak  so they won't prevent dealloction, and if the object is deallocated then you can get a reference to it again anyway because it will be gone. You should show the code as to how are using `viewWithTag`. There is no 'view of the imagview'. A UIImageView is a UIView subclass